# Silverlight Splash Screen within XAP

Tags: c#, silverlight, loading, splash-screen

Ok, this might be a silly question but...

Is it possible to have a custom xaml load/splash screen within the xap?

There is a game site I wish to upload my Silverlight game to, which only allows a single xap to be uploaded, and so I wondered whether there is a possibility of modifying the splash screen that it uses.

My gut feeling is that this is impossible, but I thought I might as well ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a true splash screen that is within the xap file. The whole point is that the splash screen is displayed while the xap file is downloading, so it can't be inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [great MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838130%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) detailing several different aspects of splash screens, as well as a [how-to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903962%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that walks you through the basic process.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom load/splash screen" ?
Are you talking about having your own custom splash screen with a game that isnt yours?

If on the otherhand you are creating the splash screen and the game itself (i.e. you own the entire Xap file), then of course what you are wanting is possible.

But maybe i'm confused because this seems like such a simple solution to me.
Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Who ever is hosting these silverlight games should be responsible for having their "splash screen" for when the xap's are loading.

However, there is nothing from preventing you to create your own splash screen(s) as these are typical within games (and no, the point of a splash screen is not necessarily to hide the downloading/loading of something, especially in a game).

Hope that helps.